# Display div below the row in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
       table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }

td {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; vertical-align: top;}

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content1').hide();
        $('#content2').hide();
        $('#content3').hide();


$("input").click(function() {
 var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr'); //parent row of the input or whatever is the click trigger
 var conDiv = $(this).data("href"); //returns #content1 - id of the content div you want shown
 var conH = $(conDiv).height(); //corresponding content div height
 var rowH = $(thisRow).height(); // this row height
 var newrowH = conH + rowH; //the new row height
 var posL = $(thisRow).position().left; // left position that div needs to be
 var posT = $(thisRow).position().top + rowH + 5 + 'px';  // top position that div needs to be ** not working properly!!


   if ( $(conDiv).is(":visible") ) {
       $(thisRow).css({"height" : "auto"});
       $(conDiv).css({"display" : "none", "left": "auto", "top" : "auto" });
   } else  {
       //reset all rows to normal height
       $("tr").css({"height" : "auto"}); 
       //expand the height of this row
       $(thisRow).css({"height" : newrowH});

       // reset all content divs.. hide them             
       $("[id*=content]").css({"display" : "none", "left": "auto", "top" : "auto"}); 
       //show the one you want
       $(conDiv).css({"display" : "block", "left": posL, "top" : posT});
   }
});

});
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="table-wrap">
<table summary="test" cellspacing="0" id="master">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="40px">
        <col span="4" width="25%">
    </colgroup>

<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
     <th><span>Customer</span></th>
     <th><span>OrderID</span></th>
     <th><span>Order date</span></th>
     <th><span>Order Total</span></th>
   </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="" value=" " data-href="#content1" ></td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td><td>10258</td><td>07/17/1996</td><td>$403.72</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="" value=" " data-href="#content2"></td>
        <td>Wartian Herkku</td><td>10270</td><td>08/01/1996</td><td>$1,376.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="" value=" " data-href="#content3"></td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td><td>10275</td><td>08/07/1996</td><td>$15.36</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="content1">
<h2>content for row 1</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>head 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div><!-- content1 -->

<div id="content2">
<h2>content for row 2</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>head 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div><!-- content2 -->
<div id="content3">
<h2>content for row 3</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>head 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div><!-- content3 -->
</div><!-- table-wrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Div should be displayed below the row on click of button. but it is displaying below the table as below.

[image]

But it should display as :

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please note: Java != Javascript!

Comment: You cannot without splitting up the table. You could designate an empty row, that spans the column length, between every row as seen in this. [how-to-put-DIV-between-table-rows](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?517923-how-to-put-DIV-between-table-rows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've a simple & effective solution to your problem. Please have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/4FKCa/)

```
$(document).delegate('input[type="button"]','click',function(){
    $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
    $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr/>').next().append('<td colspan="5"/>').children('td').append('<div/>').children().css('background','#f0f0f0').html($('#content').html());
});
```

Comment: @RupamDatta Is there anyway the div can slide down from the row?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $c=$(conDiv);

$(this).parent().parent().after("<tr><td colspan='5'>"+$c.html()+"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: add it before `$(conDiv).css({"display" : "block", "left": posL, "top" : posT});` and make get the div itself in the 'conDiv' not the id, just now noticed that condiv is an id

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().after("<tr><td colspan='5'><div>my div</div></td></tr>");`  does this add a div??

Comment: @user1016403 you able to add the div? which row's height is increasing?

Comment: That is probably coz the div at the last must have become visible too, stretching everything, see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position your "content#" divs above your table you should add `position:absolute` to them to make `top:` work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and small script,DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/JyfPg/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content1').hide();
    $('#content2').hide();
    $('#content3').hide();

    $("input").click(function () {
        if ($('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).is(":visible")) {
            $('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).remove();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr id="' + $(this).data("href") + '"><td colspan="5">' + $('#' + $(this).data("href")).html() + '</td></tr>');
        }                       
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried it. but it keeps increasing the space between the rows when u hide it. just try clicking the button several times. u will see the issue. Thanks for ur reply

Comment: have you tried this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/JyfPg/1/  I aldy changed to remove() instead of hide()..

Comment: In fiddle it is working. i copied the code into an html file then it is not working...

Comment: aww, i see, i have to update the html code too, updated to ...data-href="content1"... without #.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="detail"></td>
        <td>
            first row
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="detail"></td>
    <td>second row</td>
   </tr> 
</table>



 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var $current=$(this).parent().parent().index();
        if($(this).hasClass('clicked'))
        {
            var next=$current+1;
            $('table tr:eq('+next+')').remove();
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        }else{
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
   var $current= $(this).parent().parent().index();
       $("table tr:eq("+$current+")").after("<tr><td colspan='2'><div>AddedDiv</div></td></tr>");
        }
    });
});
```

You can add and remove the div this way please look at the demo . thanks
DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/zeewon/GpvT8/