# Is it possible to display a table cell as though it is in another row?

Tags: css

I'm generating a tabular report in HTML that needs to display certain details (notes related to the tabular data) below the row it's related to.  Picture something where the logical structure is something like this:
[image: image illustrating logical structure of data]
but which needs to be displayed with the "Promo Offer Note" field in its own row, like so:
[image]

The thing that makes this tough is that the Promo Offer Note needs to actually be in the same row as the rest of the data.  If you view source (or at least traverse the document object) you'll see the Promo Offer Note in the same row as the Item Description that says "WELCH'S REDUCED SUGAR GRAPE SQZ JELLY".

What I need to do appears on the surface to be like [what's being done in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878642/display-div-below-the-row-in-html-table) but the very very significant difference is that I need the details which are displayed below the table row to *actually be **in** that row* from a DOM point of view, whereas the solution in that question is to create a new row.

The reason for needing it all in the same row is that I want to sort the table (using the awesome [Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/) library, although the problem would exist no matter what I used).  If you add a row with a really wide cell that fills almost all the columns, you throw away the integrity of the table *as tabular data*.  By adding `<tr><td></td><td colspan=99>Promo note details here</td></tr>` I would be using non-semantic markup, which is commonly done, but prevents me from treating the table as a data source.

How can I achieve this?  How can I make a table cell display as though it is in its own row?

Here is my failed attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonzylstra/pfvPk/   If you have any good ideas you might be better off pursuing them first, since I think my attempt is a dead-end.

Comment: I've got a cleaned-up version of the working CSS & HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonzylstra/pfvPk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `float: left` on the `<td>` CSS? I think you may remove `position: absolute` from `td.note`selector.

Comment: Yes I did, but maybe you can get it working where I didn't.  Please give it a go!

Comment: Any idea how to make the other rows use 100% of the width of the row?

Comment: The more I look at this solution, the more I see holes in it.  It doesn't actually make just the "note" `td` move down, but any that don't fit (all `td`s need `float:left` for this to work).  Thus it breaks the normal behavior of the rest of the row: they all behave just like `span`s.

Comment: Is the wrapping element fixed or responsive?

Comment: You mean the element wrapping the table? There's nothing responsive yet, but this is intended to be used on a site with a responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

You need `float: left` on the TDs and `clear: both` on the TD with the note class.

### [**See working jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L44sa/)

---

### HTML

```
<table class="notes">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class="note">this is should appear to be in its own row, even though it's really on the row above. If I put lots of text into this, though, it will not expand naturally the way I want, since the whole cotton-pickin' cell is absolutely positioned. It all depends on the length of the text in this cell, and the width of the browser window. If I happen to guess just right, it may be okay. Otherwise no.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class="note">this is should appear to be in its own row, even though it's really on the row above. If I put lots of text into this, though, it will not expand naturally the way I want, since the whole cotton-pickin' cell is absolutely positioned. It all depends on the length of the text in this cell, and the width of the browser window. If I happen to guess just right, it may be okay. Otherwise no.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class="note">this is should appear to be in its own row, even though it's really on the row above. If I put lots of text into this, though, it will not expand naturally the way I want, since the whole cotton-pickin' cell is absolutely positioned. It all depends on the length of the text in this cell, and the width of the browser window. If I happen to guess just right, it may be okay. Otherwise no.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class="note">this is should appear to be in its own row, even though it's really on the row above. If I put lots of text into this, though, it will not expand naturally the way I want, since the whole cotton-pickin' cell is absolutely positioned. It all depends on the length of the text in this cell, and the width of the browser window. If I happen to guess just right, it may be okay. Otherwise no.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class="note">this is should appear to be in its own row, even though it's really on the row above. If I put lots of text into this, though, it will not expand naturally the way I want, since the whole cotton-pickin' cell is absolutely positioned. It all depends on the length of the text in this cell, and the width of the browser window. If I happen to guess just right, it may be okay. Otherwise no.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### CSS

```
html, body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
.notes tr:nth-child(even) 
{
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.notes td 
{
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
}
.note 
{
    clear: both;
    border: 1px outset #D3D3D3;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2px !important;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

---

### RESULTS

[image: jsFiddle Results]

Comment: You must have missed the part explaining why that won't work.  Putting an extra row in the table is actually not appropriate, because it breaks my ability to sort the table (and breaks the semantics of a table as a data structure).  It's got to be in the same row.

Comment: Excellent.  Works nicely.