# Is it possible to add tr inside..?

Tags: html, angularjs

Default table is like this (below is table structure)

In my case I want to list something like:

```
photo   |id | name  | address 
-------------------------------
xyz.png | 1 | temp1 |   xxxxxxx

    here is some information

abc.png | 2 | temp2 |  xxxxxxx
```

When I clicked on xyz.png image it's description is shown between the `<tr>` and another `<tr>` As I shown you in above example
and here I am using angular js and my code is like below

```
 <tbody class="giving-body" ng-repeat="(key, datedata) in abc">

            <tr class="section-top" >
                <td>[[historyinfo[key][0].contribution_date]]</td><td>[[abc[key][0].total_items]] Items</td><td>[[abc[key][0].totalimpacts]]</td><td><div class="price">US $ <strong>[[historyinfo[key][0].totalusd]]</strong></div><div>SG $ [[historyinfo[key][0].totalsgd]]</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="border-bottom giving-overview-item" ng-repeat="info in datedata" >
                <td class="hover-desc-selector">
                    <img class="impact-history-image " src="[[info.project_rect_image]]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="green">Project</span>
                    <p>[[info.project_title]]</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    2 [[info.impact_level_title]]
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="giving-overview-price-container text-right">
                        <p class="us">US $ <strong>[[info.total_amt_usd]]</strong></p>
                        <hr>
                        <p>SG $ [[info.total_amt_sgd]]</p>
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="hover-desc" ng-repeat="details in datedata" >
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div style="position: relative">
                        <div class="notch"></div>
                        <div class="slide-up"><a class="slide-up-selector"><img src="[[mybaseurl]]/icon-slide-up.png"/></a></div>
                        <p class="font-400">Project Description</p>
                        [[details.description]]
                        <br/><br/>
                        <p>Project Managed by : <strong>[[details.org_name]]</strong></p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> [[details.country_name]] 
                            <span ng-repeat="cat_info in details.category_data">
                                <span class="vertical-bar"> | </span> 
                                <i class="fa icon-moon-category"></i>
                                [[cat_info]]
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Any idea please let me know.

Comment: Why not just insert a `<tr>` at the correct position and `<td>`s having the colspan you need?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878642/display-div-below-the-row-in-html-table, just need to tune it to angularjs if needed